# Why my code doesn't work like I want? And how can I check the validty of the date?

Tags: c, validation, struct, kali-linux

**I want to let the user insert** her name and check if he inserts char just otherwise let him insert a valid name, and insert a 6 integer number for the card number otherwise let him insert a valid number then insert the expiration date. Now, How can I check that the insert a valid date?

```
int  main()
{
    char name[20];
    int cardnumber, pin;
    float balance;    
    printf("Enter your first and last name :  ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    for (int i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (!(name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z')
         || !(name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z'))
        {  
            printf("The entered name is not all  Alphabet char plz insert a valid name\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("insert your card number ~6 digit~\n ");
    scanf("%d", &cardnumber);
    if (!(sizeof(cardnumber) != 6)
     || !(cardnumber >= '0' && cardnumber <= '9'))
    {
        printf("plz insert a valid 6digit card number\n "); 
        scanf("%d", cardnumber);
    }
    struct date datei;
    printf("insert Expiration date of your card :\n");
    printf("day :");  
    scanf("%d", &datei.day);
    printf("month :");
    scanf("%d", &datei.month);
    printf("year :"); 
    scanf("%d", &datei.year);
    printf("Enter your acount Balance " );
    scanf("%d", &balance);
    printf("Enter your pin ~3digit~ :");
    // scanf("%d", &pin);
    // if (sizeof(pin)>3)
    // {printf("Enter a valid pin \n");
    // scanf("%d", &pin);}
    scanf("%d", pin);
    while (sizeof(pin) == 3)
    {
        printf("ENTER YOUR SECRET PIN NUMBER:");
        scanf("%d", &pin);
        if (sizeof(pin) != 3)
            printf("PLEASE ENTER VALID PASSWORD\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", cardnumber);` ==> `scanf("%d", &cardnumber);`. The testing logic looks wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",cardnumber);
scanf("%d",datei.day);
scanf("%d",datei.month);
scanf("%d",datei.year);
```

You missed `&` in these statements. Change these statements to :

```
scanf("%d",&cardnumber);
scanf("%d",&datei.day);
scanf("%d",&datei.month);
scanf("%d",&datei.year);
```

Comment: Why I should do that?

Comment: That is the C syntax.  Please visit man page : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html